# multi-row menu item with ncurses?

Tags: ncurses

The `menu` extension of `ncurses` seems to insist that all menu items have the same width. This means that if one menu item is very wide and the others are narrow, then a lot of space is wasted and the screen width does not suffice.

One workaround I thought of is to split the long menu item into several rows by using the `set_menu_spacing` function:

```
set_menu_spacing(myMenu, 1, 2, 1); // all menu items will get two rows
```

However, I do not know how to get my wide item to use those two rows. I tried to insert `\n` into the string representing the item, but that resulted in hiding all the items beginning with the item in whose name `\n` appears. What should I do to get the multi-row items to work?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no, you cannot do this with the existing library.

Noting that [`set_menu_spacing`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/menu_spacing.3x.html) is an ncurses *extension*, the library does not check for newlines in the item name or description.

The ncurses menu (and form and panel) libraries were written for compatibility with [System V's menu](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/menu.3x.html#h2-PORTABILITY), form, panel libraries (essentially SCO and Solaris, since AIX and HPUX do not have these libraries).  A quick check of Solaris 10 shows that it did not expect embedded newlines either.  However, it might be a useful *extension* since there are no useful programs which would break if ncurses were modified to do something useful in this case.

Comment: So, that parameter is only for spacing and the extra rows cannot be non-empty, correct? Is there any other way to make the menu more compact when only one item's name is long?